# Using Agile.net Code Protection with ClickOnce applications

Tags: .net, clickonce, obfuscation

I've developed a click once application I'd like to protect using [Agile.net .net obfuscator](http://secureteam.net/Obfuscator.aspx), what would be the proper way to protect click once assemblies, and then package them so that they can be deployed as click once applications.

Any help on this matter is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting v6.3 Agile.net obfuscator accepts click once deployment manifest as inputs. This means you can add your .application as a direct input to [Agile.net obfuscator](http://secureteam.net/docs/ClickOnce-Deployments.aspx) and it will read it and list all assemblies inside the project file.

You can then set your protection configuration, process your assemblies and resign them.

The result a protected click once package that can be deployed to your clients.